# How to merge two different groupings if they are not disjoint with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose that I have two sets of identifiers `id1` and `id2` in a data frame. How can I create a new identifier `id3` that works as follows:

I consider `id1` as the stricter key, so that observations are first grouped in `id1` and then in `id2`. If there are two sets of rows with different values of `id2` that have some of its elements with the same `id1`, these two sets should have the same value for `id3` (the exact value in `id3` doesn't matter much).

```
 df <- data.frame(id1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 6),
             id2 = c(4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 7),
             id3 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3))
```

Rows 1 and 2 are grouped together because they have the same `id1`. Rows 3, 4 and 5 are grouped together because 3 and 4 have the same `id1` and 4 and 5 have the same `id2`.

Can someone help? I would rather have a solution with `dplyr` that encompasses a general case in which there is an arbitrary number of possible values in the `id` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a graph theory problem. Each `id1` and `id2` is a separate node and `df` gives the links between them. You are looking to see which weakly connected clusters each id belongs too.

```
library(igraph)
df <- df %>% mutate(from = paste0('id1', '_', id1), to = paste0('id2', '_', id2))
dg <- graph_from_data_frame(df %>% select(from, to), directed = FALSE)
df <- df %>% mutate(id3 = components(dg)$membership[from])
df %>% select(id1, id2, id3)

#>   id1 id2 id3
#> 1   1   4   1
#> 2   1   3   1
#> 3   2   1   2
#> 4   2   2   2
#> 5   5   2   2
#> 6   6   7   3
```

Comment: thank you! did not know of this package! Does this scale well for very large datasets?

Comment: I guess it depends how very large. It should be about as good as you can expect.

Comment: Can you help me with a very similar case? I want to relate vectors in a list that are weakle connected. This  ```list(c(1,2,3), c(3,4,5), c(5), c(6))``` should yield ```list(1, 1, 1, 2)```

Comment: I think that's different enough that it deserves its own question!

Comment: here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984825/assign-the-same-index-if-two-vectors-have-a-common-intersection