# Using igraph to find chained observations with exceptions

Tags: r, igraph

this question is a follow-up from two previous ones:

[How to merge two different groupings if they are not disjoint with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908856/how-to-merge-two-different-groupings-if-they-are-not-disjoint-with-dplyr/63911339?noredirect=1#comment113015621_63911339)

[Assign the same index if two vectors have a common intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984825/assign-the-same-index-if-two-vectors-have-a-common-intersection/63988447#63988447)

I want, as in these questions, to assign the same index to observations that are linked, directly or indirectly through a series of groups. For instance, let's say `id1` and `id2`.

But now I wonder if I could somehow add a twist to this process. I still want to link these observations. But the matching following only happens if the final result follows two rules: no matches from `id1` are broken, no pairings between observations with the same date.

Below I show a toy example with expected output:

```
df <- tribble(~Year, ~Quarter, ~ id1, ~ id2,
               2009,  4,         3,     2,
               2010,  2,         3,     2,
               2010,  2,         1,     4,
               2010,  2,         2,     1,
               2010,  3,         1,     3,
               2011,  1,         2,     2,
               2011,  4,         6,     7,
               2012,  1,         5,     2
              ) 

old_way <- tribble(~Year, ~Quarter, ~ id1, ~ id2, ~ id3,
                    2009,  4,         3,     2,     1,
                    2010,  1,         3,     2,     1,
                    2010,  1,         1,     4,     2,
                    2010,  1,         2,     1,     1,
                    2010,  3,         1,     3,     2,
                    2011,  1,         2,     2,     1,
                    2011,  4,         4,     5,     3,
                    2012,  1,         5,     2,     1
                   )

new_way <- tribble(~Year, ~Quarter, ~ id1, ~ id2, ~ id3,
                    2009,  4,         3,     2,     1,
                    2010,  1,         3,     2,     1,
                    2010,  1,         1,     4,     2,
                    2010,  1,         2,     1,     3,
                    2010,  3,         1,     3,     2,
                    2011,  1,         2,     2,     3,
                    2011,  4,         4,     5,     4,
                    2011,  1,         5,     2,     1
                   )
```

Consider `old_way`, in which the date plays no role. Rows 1 and 2 are grouped together because they have the same `id1`. Rows 6 and 8 join them because by having the same `id2`. Finally, row 4 also joins them because it has the same `id1` as row 6.

Rows 3 and 5 are joined to each other due to`id1`. Row 7 doesn't have any intersections.

Going to `new_way`, columns `Year` and `Quarter` enter as blocks to some matches - Rows 2 and 4 can't be matched anymore, since both are `2010/2`.

So, even though row 6 matches rows 1 and 2 by `id2`, it cannot join them, because it has the same `id1` value as row 4, and row 4 has the same date as row 2.

The precedence relation then works as follows: different dates, `id1`, `id2`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm little unclear about your connection rules, especially the "new way" date impact, but here is generic approach using `igraph`:

1. Add unique id (let's call it `vertexId`) to your data frame (to represent vertices)
2. Define edges data frame (`e`) as union of joins on each `id1`, `id2` etc. and filtering the date; the `e` data.frame should have `vertexIdLeft` and `vertexIdRight` for each valid pair
3. Create graph as `g <- graph_from_data_frame(e, directed = FALSE)
4. Identify related entries using connected component algorithm `c <- components(g)`

Comment: but how would this account for observations with the same Date not being matched?

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito The filter the join in step #2. Join ensures `id1`, `id2` match, filter removes those edges having the same date and the same id.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but I'm afraid it won't work, and here is why: you suggest to filter observations based on different dates only **before** making the connections - you only control for **not pairing directly** observations with the same date. In the example given in the question, this wouldn't give me any difference. However, what I need is more involved: I want to also prevent the **indirect pairing** of rows with the same date.

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito what if you arbitrary drop members with duplicate date __after__ the grouping described above is done (judging arbitrary is OK based on your discussion with @pseudospin). If you want to be more predicable, you could drop members with low betweenness centrality (i.e. those connecting fewest group members). The code would used betweenes centrality calculation for each group members, row number function partitioned by group and filter, all after the step #4.

Answer (score 0):

I think this time the question is ill-formed, unfortunately. At the least, it doesn't have a unique answer. Considering the walked through example in the question:

Row 2 joins to row 1, rows 1 and 2 join to row 6, and row 6 joins to row 4. However it is forbidden for row 4 and 2 to be in the same cluster as they share the same `(Year, Quarter)`. The problem is where do you put the other 'break' between the two clusters. You've chosen to put it on the link between rows 1,2 and row 6 but you could just as easily have put it between rows 4 and 6 and still satisfied the constraints.

Perhaps you mean that rows with the same `id1` have to join together which would force the break to be between rows 4 and 6, but cases where the chain was longer would still be ambiguous.

Comment: You're right. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The division you mentioned was not arbitrary on my part: rows 4 and 6 can't be split up because they share the same id1. Now regarding the ambiguity, I am having trouble to think about how would this come up, if "chain was longer" vou meant having more columns to match, this wouldn't happen in my case. It will always have two sets of groups forming a third one

Comment: By longer chain I mean something like row A joins to row B joins to row C ... joins to row Z, and row A and Z share the same `id1` but alsohave the same `(Year, Quarter)` so can't be in the same cluster. Which cluster do rows B to Y belong to? The one starting from row A, or the one starting from row Z?

Comment: I see what you mean. If there was a solution, I wouldn't mind it picking any of A or Z. At first sight, any arbitrary choice would be ok to me

Comment: So just do it as before, and then for any Year/Quarter that have two identical id1s extract one of them into a cluster entirely on its own?